# Переход от «preg_replace()» к «preg_replace_callback()»

Tags: php

Нужна помощь с переписыванием `preg_replace` в `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$send_mess = preg_replace("/private \[(.*)\]/Ue","'<span class=user-to-private data=\"'.(('\\1' != '" . $user['login'] . "')?'\\1':'" . $send_login ."').'\">private [</span><span class=user-to-private name=\"\\1\" data=\"'.(('\\1' != '". $user['login'] . "')?'\\1':'" . $send_login ."').'\">\\1</span><span class=user-to-private data=\"'.(('\\1' != '". $user['login'] . "')?'\\1':'" . $send_login ."').'\">]</span>'", $send_mess);
```

*P.S.* Мануалы читал, но ничего не вышло. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: извиняюсь, не разобрался малость и вставил че-попало(

Comment: заранее извиняюсь, изначально не разобрался с интерфейсом

Comment: так оно изначально так )) есть исходная строка $send_mess,  в ней ищется "private" и заменяется на тот кошмар, что идет дальше. Беда в том, что перестает работать в php7.2, исходя их мануала, нужно preg_replace заменить на preg_replace_callback. соответственно, в этом и проблема. не хватает понимания

Comment: строка взята из работающего проекта под пхп5.4.
пхп7.2 ругается на модификатор /e и не выполняет этот код. именно из за этого нужно использовать preg_replace_callback. но, сама строка сложная и я в тупике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *строка взята из работающего проекта под пхп5.4. пхп7.2 ругается на модификатор /e и не выполняет этот код. именно из за этого нужно использовать preg_replace_callback*

На *preg_replace_callback()* код будет выглядеть так:

```
$send_mess = preg_replace_callback(
    '~private \[(.*?)\]~',
    function ($m) use (&$user, &$send_login){
        return '<span class=user-to-private data="'
            . ($m[1] != $user['login'] ? $m[1] : $send_login)
            . '">private [</span><span class=user-to-private name="'
            . $m[1] . '" data="' . ($m[1] != $user['login'] ? $m[1] : $send_login)
            . '">' . $m[1] . '</span><span class=user-to-private data="'
            . ($m[1] != $user['login'] ? $m[1] : $send_login) . '">]</span>';
    },
    $send_mess
);

echo $send_mess;
```

---

Возвращает он такую же строку, как и ваш аналог. Ну а раз вы говорите, что так и надо, то так и будет. Хотя конечно прочитать такой код не реально.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь. автор этого творения не я, я столкнулся с необходимостью адаптировать этот "код" под пхп7.2

Answer (score 1):

Необходимые данные:

```
$user['login'] = 'Юзер_Логин';
$send_login = 'Логин';

$send_mess = 'private [что-то]';
```

Сама переписанная конструкция:

```
$send_mess = preg_replace_callback(
    '/private \[(.*)]/U',
    function ($call) use ($user, $send_login)
    {
        $logic = $call[1] != $user['login'] ? $call[1] : $send_login;

        return "
            <span class=user-to-private data=\"{$logic}\">private [</span>
            <span class=user-to-private name=\"{$call[1]}\" data=\"{$logic}\">{$call[1]}
            </span><span class=user-to-private data=\"{$logic}\">]</span>
        ";
    },
    $send_mess
);
```